# Setting up CNAME at DirectNIC.com caused gmail in Google Apps for Businesses to stop working

Tags: email, gmail, cname, mx-record

I am helping a friend set up a website at Drupal Gardens. The domain is www.fromtheheartyoga.com. Previously the site was hosted at Modwest. While at Modwest I set them up with gmail/Google Apps for business (free version), so they could use the @fromtheheartyoga.com emails with gmail.

A few days ago I moved hosting from Modwest to Drupal Gardens. In order to get the domain working correctly I had to set up a CNAME record at DirectNIC (the domain provider) to point the domain "www.fromtheheartyoga.com" at the Drupal Garden site "fthy.drupalgardens.com". In order to do this I had to upgrade the DirectNIC account to a hosted account.

When I created the CNAME record, email stopped working. I later went in and updated the MX records at DirectNIC with all of the relevant Google Mail MX information. Email still didn't work. DirectNIC sait it could take as long as 48 hour for these changes to propagate. Thing is, when I updated the CNAME record, the domain began pointing to the new hosting environment almost immediately. Not so with the email.

That was Friday. As of today, none of the email addresses using the @fromtheheartyoga.com (gmail) have received any email. Every email I send from another account disappears into the internet. For the emails I send from my personal gmail account, I occasionally get a transfer update which includes, among other things the note that "The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect".

I can still send from the @fromtheheartyoga gmail account. Replies to emails sent from there also disappear.

I have had no luck with Google searches, unless the answer is right in front of me and I simply don't know enough about the issue to recognize it. Likewise here at StackOverflow. Any insights would be greatly appreciated

-John Winkelman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compatibility reasons, you can't put a CNAME in the root domain; doing so will break email.
Use an A record instead.

Comment: Hmm.... I removed the CNAME for "fromtheheartyoga.com" and kept the one for "www.fromtheheartyoga.com". Lo and behold, an email I sent on Friday came through! Am currently talking with DirectNIC about setting up a 301 redirect to point "fromtheheartyoga.com" at "www.fromtheheartyoga.com". I have not heard back from them yet. Thanks for the info; I am getting closer to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an A record for fromtheheartofyoga.com. The old BIND4 CNAME for a domain directive really wasn't right even back then. It's just more records to edit should you move again, who cares.

Edit to add: I don't know whether you get a definite IP address with your hosting service, you would have to know that for this to work.

Regards,
Brian in CA

Comment: Thanks for the info. At DrupalGardens users can use either one, but since DG is in "the cloud", they recommend CNAME over A records.